# Adding Static Files To Project By T4Scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

I am generating an CMS by using T4Scaffolder and all the CS files are being generated successfully. But also I want to add  some css and png files to the project.

What is the best way to add static files to MVC Web Application with a powershell comment ?

I can even add css files to project by adding t4 templates for each one but I cannot do same thing for image files. I need something to copy a existing folder to the MVC Web Application project.

Comment: Have you checked out mvcscaffolding?  Steven Sanderson has an excellent blog post on adding a custom collection of files.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/08/mvcscaffolding-scaffolding-custom-collections-of-files/

Answer (score 0):

Build a nuget package, you will then be able to use both scaffolders as well as adding static content such as images etc